# Testing methods that don't return anything

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to wrap my head around testing, and I know it's easier than I think. My guess is that I'm going to inevitably have trouble because I wrote the code first and am just now doing tests, instead of having a test driven development process.

My question is about functions that do something like including files. They don't return anything, but they do something for the script as a whole.

Let's say I have a class that includes a file:

```
<?php 

class Includer {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->include_file("/var/www/index.html");
    }

    public function check_file_validity($file = "") {
        // Check to see if the file exists
        return true; // if exists
    }

    public function include_file($file = "") {
        if ($this->check_file_validity($file)) {
            include $file;
        }        
    }
}
```

I can write a test to assert that the file exists (`check_file_validity`), and that would be straight forward.

However, would it be acceptable to return a boolean on the `include_file` function based on whether or not the file was included? Wouldn't that be a redundant test since basically the same thing is happening when running the `check_file_validity` function?

I should note that the information given to include the file is coming from the URL, so no files here would be hard coded outside of the tests (unless I mock the `$_GET` parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I think it's safe to assume PHP functions work, and there's no need to test them again. Instead, if you want to test the code that uses a function like `include`, it might be a good idea to wrap around it. So the code could look like this:

```
<?php 

class Includer {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->include_file("/var/www/index.html");
    }

    public function check_file_validity($file = "") {
        // Check to see if the file exists
        return true; // if exists
    }

    public function include_file_if_exists($file = "") {
        if ($this->check_file_validity($file)) {
            $this->include_file($file);
        }        
    }

    public function include_file($file = "") {
        include $file;
    }
}
```

To test `include_file_if_exists()`, you'd simply mock your class, so you can check whether `include_file()` was called or not, and if it got the correct argument.

As for `include_file()` itself, it's not necessary to test it anymore, as it only wraps `include`.

Comment: Would you say that would bloat the code, making it harder to track down issues in the long run because of the added functions? Your answer does help me understand what to do, so thank you for that.

Comment: It depends. Usually you want to group these kind of functionalities, so instead of adding an `include` method, you might want to consider a reusable loader object. Or if you want to parse text files, you'd create a `Reader` class and use that instead of raw PHP functions. But you don't have to test everything. And in your case, it'd be perfectly fine to just test `check_file_validity`. But I wanted to show you how to still be able to test methods using such functions if the logic gets more complicated.